# Alert the returned data

Tags: angularjs, lua

I am working with AngularJs4 . I am trying to verify each user at server side. Server side contains a lua page  and returns a name.

**

```html
var result = this._http.post("http://192.168.0.102:8000/user.lua",uname,pass)
      
      alert(result)
```

**user.lua**

```html
require "string"
function handle(r)
local POST, POSTMULTI = r:parsebody()
local name = POST['uname']
local pass = POST['pass']
r.content_type = "text/plain"
if r.method == 'POST' then
r:puts("\n...The Log Detailsss...\n\n") 
        for k, v in pairs( POST,POSTMULTI ) do
          r:puts( string.format("%s: %s\n\n", k, v) )
--file:write(string.format("%s: %s\n\n", k, v))
return "hello"
    end  
    return "name"
end
```

**

When run the application it retuns like..
[image]

what will I do..Please help ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to **[`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** the response inorder to show in alert

```
var result = this._http.post("http://192.168.0.102:8000/user.lua",uname,pass)
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: A better practice would be to dump this data to the JavaScript console using [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

Comment: thanks for the response..sorry,,..It will not work for me.  my returning data is not a JSON it is a string . when i use JSON.stringfy() in result , it shows... "  {"_isScalar":false} " instead of [object,object]...any other solution

Comment: What do you want to see?

Comment: I want to simply see the returned value from my server page. here server page returns "name" . So i want to display it in angular client side . I used alert(result) , but it will not work.

Comment: according to your above comment it does not return name

Comment: user.lua returns "name" isn't it ? . it is the server page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155999/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-vinu-prasad).